# How to get the SELinux context of a specified file on Android?

Tags: android, selinux

I'm developing a SU-aware app for Android, and found that SELinux context configuration and policies on some devices are slightly different than others.

Is there any public or hidden API of Android SDK to query SELinux context of a specified file, like what "ls -Z" provides in shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/SELinux.java

And maybe You know how to set SELinux scontext for Android Application from store. 
I want change utrusted_app for my custom domain.

Comment: I don't think you can set (change) context in app without root.